# Receiving requests but not processing

Tags: dns, apache-http-server

I have an apache server set up on my computer. I have my port forwarding set up, so in the browser, it looks like the server receives the request, but it's not processing it. Anyone know what might be the reasons for this?

Here is the link to the vHost file with the DNS replaced, since this won't display it properly. http://www.codeshare.io/6v904

Also, when the server starts, I get this error message:

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So the real solution was that the make_sock error was thrown when there are two `Listen 80` statements, so if you take one out, the make_sock error disappears. And the "hang up" error when requesting the public IP address is caused by the router not allowing to access computer on the network through pubic IP but only through private IP.